# trouble connecting two mysql tables

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble trying to link to tables together in mysql (using php version 5.4) with user_id being the key. For example, I have a table called as_users for my users and new users are assigned an auto incremented user_id. Then I created the Test table (which I did using the code below). But when a new user registers, the user is only added to the as_users table (let's say they become user_id 3. But my Test is still just showing my one user_id (user_id 1) which I manually entered into Test.

What am I missing to get the Test table user_id records to match the as_users table?

Needless to say I am a newbie and not sure if the syntax below is correct and if I should user FK or CONSTRAIN syntax to connect these tables.

This is how I created my Test table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
user_id int NOT NULL,
interests varchar(255) NOT NULL,
bio mediumtext,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES as_users(user_id)
)
```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would still need to manually insert the record into both tables... Foreign keys don't take care of that for you automatically.

You might be able to accomplish this with a trigger, though I would strongly recommend against that approach.

Comment: Isn't that the whole idea of foreign keys though? That one table can connect with another one? If a user logs in, there is the users table. And when they do something like buy something, the purchase is stored in an orders table. And the orders table is able to track the orders by that user. So there is a need for the two tables to connect . There's no way a person is going in an manually updating the orders table for a user. That is done automatically, and I'm trying to figure out how...

Comment: @user5000 Not at all... The only point of foreign keys is to ensure _data integrity_... Meaning, to guarantee that a record will not be "orphaned" and will have a corresponding record in a related table. You can have a database built entirely without foreign keys (and I've seen very large ones that don't use them at all) and not lose any functionality if you take that route. Foreign keys are only there to ensure "clean" data.

Comment: @user5000 You can do JOINs without any foreign keys at all... In the JOIN, you specify which columns you want to JOIN on. They do not need to have foreign keys and can be arbitrary (you can join on ID, or name, or anything else you want). A foreign key simply guarantees that the JOIN won't fail by ensuring that there IS a record in the other table and it wasn't deleted, but that's about it...

Comment: Fair enough. So then foreign keys is not the way to connect tables. So how would I connect two tables using the user_id key?

Comment: @user5000 Just use the JOIN statement when SELECTing data... For example, 'SELECT * FROM as_users u JOIN orders o ON o.user_id = u.user_id WHERE u.user_id = 12345'...

Comment: @user5000 What a FOREIGN KEY will do, in your case, is only ensure that you can't, for example, delete a user who still has orders... You would need to delete their orders first, or reassign them to a different user, before you can delete the user from the as_users table.

Comment: That would be great for doing select queries. But how would I first populate both tables so that I can then user this join statement? That is, I can't imagine that I have to go to an orders table and manually create a record and be sure to give it user_id that is the same as the user_id in my login (as_users) table. This should happen automatically. I just can't figure out how.

Comment: To clarify...when a user signs up, they are in the users table. But nothing happens in my orders table because the orders is not connected to the users...

Comment: @user5000 That must always be done manually. There are ways around it, for example by using a trigger, but that opens up a whole other can of worms and I suggest avoiding TRIGGERs completely unless it's a very simple database.

Comment: @User5000 Right, you would need to create the orders separately after the user exists and you have the new user's ID (which you would then use for populating orders)

Comment: So if a user on Amazon buys something, an amazon employee has to manually go to an orders table and type in the product info for that user in an orders table? There are millions of things being purchased everyday, so I have to think php and mysql can do all of this automatically no?

Comment: @user5000 If you want a user record to be created for you behind the scenes when you create an order, I suggest using a stored procedure which will check if a record for the user exists, and use the existing ID if they do or create a new record and use that ID if they don't. That way, your logic is centralized and it's still only one call from your application.

Comment: @user5000 No, you would either have a stored procedure if you want to keep in in the database, or use an ORM which would be configured to create that record automatically if you want to do it from the application.

Comment: Oh and yes...i understand that the user needs to be created first. My question is simply how you can then reference the user in the orders table so that an order can be added to the orders table for that user?

Comment: @user5000 You get your application to use their user ID after a record for them is created and then put that into the orders table. How else would your application know which user to create the orders for? If a user logs in, their ID might be, for example, stored in the session... Then you pass that user ID into your stored procedure (or pass the user object into your ORM, which would do the same thing - grab the ID) and use it to create the order.

Comment: That is...don't I need to create an orders table that also has the same user_id column? And how does that table know this user_id is the same thing as the user_id in the users table?

Comment: @user5000 Yes, you do need the user_id in the orders table... And that user_id has to be passed in manually and populated along with the rest of the order.

Comment: Ok. almost got it. So when creating the orders table, there is no special thing I need to do so that mysql knows these two tables are related? Are you saying all I need is CREATE TABLE TEST (
user_id int NOT NULL) and there is never any need to connect this user_id to the users table user_id?

Comment: @user5000 Yep, exactly. There is nothing else you need to do. Of course, you SHOULD connect them with a foreign key just because it's good design, but you definitely don't need to. Foreign keys do almost nothing for the database itself; they just give you peace of mind.

Comment: I just assumed I was doing something wrong in mysql because I get no result when I run this code: $result = $db->select("SELECT * FROM 'Orders' WHERE 'user_id' = :id", array( 'id' => $userId ) );
echo $result['order'];

Comment: @user5000 Well that code should work... Unless there are no orders for that user in the database. It won't give you the user's record, it will just give you their orders...

Comment: Ok. Well, thanks for the clarity. If I can't get this to go I will post a new question later that is more clear.

Comment: btw, there is an entry for that user_id number in orders. But my code will not return it

Comment: @user5000 Does it return anything if you run that query from MySQL workbench? If yes, the problem is in your PHP code... Either there is no actual ID in your variable, or you're processing the results wrong...

Comment: I don't use workbench. My users table has a record with user_id value of "2". In my orders table, I used myphpadmin to insert a record with user_id value of 2 and some text in the orders field. But it will not return that orders text with the code I mentioned, which is why I thought I needed to connect the tables in mysql or something.

Comment: @user5000 No, if it's in the table then your query should definitely return it. The problem is in your PHP code... try setting it explicitly to "2" in the query instead of :id and see if that works. I wish I could help with this but I haven't done PHP for years and wouldn't know.

Comment: Yes, it does work when I set it to 2 explicity. After that worked, I began this question/thread because I figured it had to be a mysql issue and that I needed to relate the tables somehow

Comment: No, MySQL isn't even aware of the difference between "2" and :id because PHP is supposed to replace that :id with "2" for you before sending it over to MySQL (well, it's not as simple as that, but that's the gist). So it's definitely a problem with the variable you're trying to use as the :id.

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much! I'll keep at it.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

I don't fully understand the issue.  It sounds like you are inserting a record into `as_users` and you expect a record to appear in `test`.  That is not how these constraints work.  The foreign key constraint says that *when* you load a record into `test`, then the `user_id` column will need to be a valid key in `as_users`.

If you want to add a record into both tables when you insert into `as_users`, then you would need an insert trigger.  However, how would it know what values to insert for `interests` and `bio` when doing the insert?

Comment: I think my question is misunderstood because I am asking something much more basic. Mysql is a relational database, so I just want to understand how to relate two tables. If I have a users table and an orders table, how to I join them so that the purchase data is saved in another table (orders). If this can't be done, there is no point for a relational database and everything would need to be in one table.

Comment: Your comment seems totally unrelated to your question.  Clearly, there is a point to relational databases because they are in widespread use, many of them with purchase data properly normalized in multiple tables.  Think about what your question really is, and ask another question that is clearer.